# mysql and phpthumb killing the server

Tags: imagemagick, high-load, gd

I installed `GD and ImageMagick`  the other day and since that day `phpthumb()` which it is installed on my wordpress killing the processor.

I've transfered my website from an old server to this new one using `resync` 2 days ago, and I noticed that the script is not working and I checked it's php check demo and saw it was missing those 2.

Also, this one is killing my server,

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-
error=/var/lib/mysql/server.x1q.com.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/server.x1q.com.pid
```

I hope I can get help here. The server was down for 2 days due to the very high load on it.
Now it is back, and I have suspended my website to stop phpthumb problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are generating the thumbnails dynamically?   Is there anyway to generate the thumbnails onto files and then statically make them available and load them?  You could possibly do this in the background scanning for new files and processing only them.

I would NOT store any pictorial information into the database, but I would store basically their filenames on the disk kinda like an index really.